# Converting/Casting int to string in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I am trying to pull from a database in which whoever developed the database defined a column as a `string` when the only data that's in the column is scientific notation so it should have been defined as an `int`. When I create the query to pull it works when I hardcode the value in there it works but then when I try to add in a parameter it doesn't work anymore. Here is the query harcoded:

```
SELECT EYE_COLOR, HAIR_COLOR, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE AGE = 4E3
```

Here is the query when I add in parameter:

```
 SELECT EYE_COLOR, HAIR_COLOR, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE AGE = :AGE
```

The first query returns a datatable with 24 rows (as it should) but the second one only returns 13 rows. My guess is since the column is defined as a string when the parameter is being passed in something is messing up with the value. I'm using sqldeveloper and oracle.

Comment: What is the difference in the result sets returned? If you include 'AGE' in the output what comes back for both results?

Comment: scientific notation is does not map to an INT. What about 4E-3, or 1.233E7?

Comment: What is the value of :AGE you are using?  SHow exact literal, please.

Comment: Ah sorry it took so long. when it prompts for me to enter a value for :AGE I enter `4.4E3` and it returns 13 rows. But when I hardcode `4.4E3` in instead of using the parameter it returns just fine

Comment: Well, it is probably converting your age value to a string.

Comment: Yeah.. I tried the `TO_CHAR` function haven't had any luck though...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_binary_integer('4E3') "some_age_huh?"
  FROM dual;

SQL> 1251

SELECT to_char(4.4E3) FROM dual;

SQL> 400
```